# Studying this sum: $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (k+1)(x)^k$

Tags: limits, summation, riemann-sum

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (k+1)(x)^k\Longrightarrow x=-\frac{9}{10} \Longrightarrow\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (k+1)\left(-\frac{9}{10}\right)^k=\frac{100}{361}\approx 0.2777$$
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (k+1)(x)^k\Longrightarrow x=-\frac{99}{100} \Longrightarrow\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (k+1)\left(-\frac{99}{100}\right)^k=\frac{10000}{39601}\approx 0.2525$$
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (k+1)(x)^k\Longrightarrow x=-\frac{999}{1000} \Longrightarrow\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (k+1)\left(-\frac{999}{1000}\right)^k=\frac{1000000}{3996001}\approx 0.25025$$
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (k+1)(x)^k\Longrightarrow x=-\frac{99999999}{10^{8}} \Longrightarrow\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (k+1)\left(-\frac{99999999}{10^{8}}\right)^k=\frac{10^{16}}{39999999600000001}\approx 0.2500000025$$

So my conclusion will be that when $x$ get to $-1$ the sum becomes $\frac{1}{4}$ so than this will be equal:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow-1}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (k+1)(x)^k\right)=\lim_{x\rightarrow-1}\left(\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}\right)=\frac{1}{\lim_{x\rightarrow-1} (1-x)^2}=\frac{1}{4}$$

and that is than equal to:

$$1-2+3-4+5-6+7-8+9-10+...=\frac{1}{4}$$

Can someone tell me if this is right? And if it is not can you proof it?

Comment: What do you mean by $\Rightarrow$ ? Because in the usual sense, $\sum\Rightarrow x=smth$ doesn't mean anything as far as I know

Comment: I choose a value for $x$ and put it into the sum

Comment: You talk about $x$ being $-1$ but then write $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}$, so I assume that you actually mean $\lim\limits_{x\to -1}$?

Comment: Why you take the limit as $x\rightarrow 0$ if you want $x\rightarrow -1$?

Comment: For the original question (I second @Hippalectryon regarding the notation, this is not the meaning of the symbol): the sum you have does not actually converge (i.e., $\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k k$ is not even defined: the general term does not go to zero).

Comment: *Third* question by this OP on this exact theme. Third time the OP will insist that $1-2+3-4+\ldots$ is you-know-what because their prof told them so, will be explained the difference between Ramanujan summation of a sequence and convergence of the series, and will not listen. Is this an abuse of the site or what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The terms of the form $(k+1)x^k$ are convergent to zero for $x$ in the interval $(-1,1)$.  So the limit for their sum, as you've calculated, is correct.

That being said, you cannot then deduce the last summation, as you're applying it to a point where the terms of the sum are not convergent.  The expression only makes sense on the open interval, and so cannot be be evaluated at the boundary.

Comment: Actually, sometimes it can, under some hypothesis (see Tauber's theorem and related). This sort of results do not (and cannot) apply here.

Comment: @Maciek so the sum at the bottem ISN'T right?

Comment: @JanEerland no, it is not. The left-hand side actually isn't even mathematically defined according to the usual rules.

Comment: @ClementC. but not defined is thus not wrong, so if it is not defined it isn't wrong

Comment: "Not defined" means "makes no sense mathematically, unless you give a consistent definition." As it is, the last line *does not even have a meaning.*, no more than writing $dsvnsoavnkSLVLNlS = \frac{1}{4}$. You can only reason with quantities and concepts that have a definition.

Comment: @ClementC. but my prof. told me that I'll get $\frac{1}{4}$

Comment: Then ask him what he meant. If it *did* say that "$\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^{k+1} k = \frac{1}{4}$," then ask him what it means in the first place: **how* he defines "$\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^{k+1} k$". Surely, this is not the standard definition of the sum of a series.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking at $\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty (k+1)x^k$. One easily identifies this as the taylor series of $$f(x)=\frac{1}{(x-1)^2}$$ at $x=0$. Although the domain of this function is $\mathbb R\setminus\{1\}$, the taylor series does not need to converge on the domain but only on the radius of convergence. In this case we get $r=1$, meaning that we can only say that the taylor series converges for $|x|<1$ and for these $x$ the taylor series converges to the value of $f$.

For $|x|=1$ we can't make any statement yet and you have to manually check for convergence. In this case you get $\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty (k+1)$ and $\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty (k+1)\cdot(-1)^k$ and these series do not converge. This means, that you can't extend the taylor series to represent the function on $[-1,1]$ and therefore you do not get $$1-2+3-\dots=\frac 14.$$

Comment: my prof. told me I'll get $\frac{1}{4}$

Comment: You'll get $\frac {1}{4}$ for what? If you mean $$\lim\limits_{x\to -1} \frac{1}{(x-1)^2}=\frac 14$$ then yes, you will get this because the domain of $f$ is $\mathbb R\setminus\{1\}$ and as a rational function $f$ is continuous on its domain. But you do NOT get $\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty (k+1)\cdot (-1)^k=\frac {1}{4}$ as I pointed out in my answer.